# How to bring an activity to the foreground from inside the activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to bring an activity to the foreground from inside the activity. I am implementing multiple applications that do not cover the whole screen, so you can see other applications (activities) in the background and even touch them. The activities in the background react to the on touch event (e.g. one of its buttons is pressed), but it is not getting focus. This is what I would like to change. I want the activity to get focus and come to the foreground, whenever it is touched.
I tried to call startActivity from inside, but this resulted in either starting a new activity or no reaction at all (depending on the used intent flags). I want to achieve the exact same behavior that is shown when the activity is called from recent activities window. (the window opened when you long press the home button); bring the existing activity from the background to the foreground and focus it.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried configuring the activity in the manifest as `android:launchMode="singleTop"`?
This way, when you launch your activity when it is already running, a duplicate won't be started.
More info here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html